# Marionette Composite View data populating error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am new and just start learning Marionete and backnone, i am trying to using Module and display, some record so far i been unsuccessful, and there is little example i can found in the Internet i would be glad if someone can help me. i couldnt figure out why the (leader-table ) is display three time.

Output on the UI, instead of population the value, the template (leader-table) is display three time.

==============================

Fistname    Lastname

Fistname    Lastname

Fistname    Lastname

==============================

HTML PRODUCE

```
<table id="mylist" class="table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tbody> </tbody>
<table id="mylist" class="table-striped table-bordered">
<table id="mylist" class="table-striped table-bordered">
```

==============================

```
 <div id="AppBase"></div>   
<script type="text/template" id="leader-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
      <th>Fistname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="user-list">
  <td><%= fname %></td>
    <td><%= lname %></td>
</script>
```

```
 $(function () {

 var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

  app.addRegions({
  appRegion: '#AppBase'
   });

app.module('App',function(UserModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

UserModule.UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { fname: '',lname: ''}
});

UserModule.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModule.UserModel,
    comparator: 'lname'
});

UserModule.UserItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: '#user-list',
});

UserModule.TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
tagName: "table",
id: "mylist",

className: "table-striped table-bordered",
template: "#leader-table",
itemView:  UserModule.UserItemView,

appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
 collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
}

});
UserModule.addInitializer(function(){
    var UserList = [];
        UserList.push({fname: 'John',lname: 'Taylor' });
        UserList.push({fname: 'Smith', lname: 'Price'});
    var datalist = new UserModule.UserCollection(UserList);
    var UserCollectionView = new UserModule.TableView({collection: datalist});
    app.appRegion.show(UserCollectionView);
});
});

  app.start();

});
```

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: @Evgeniy there no error on the console

Comment: Which version of Marionette you are using?

Comment: i download the lastest one 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot has been changed in [Marionette V2.2.0](http://marionettejs.com/docs/current) so your code need to be changed as well.

In your `UserModule.TableView` [compositeView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html) you don't need to use `appendHtml`(used in old versions, now its called [`attachHtml`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-attachhtml)) method to attach `itemView`s to the template.

Just add new attribute named [`childViewContainer`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-childviewcontainer) (for older version it called `itemViewContainer`), and specify selector where `itemView`s need to be appended.

Here a few attrubutes which you need to change:

> itemView -> childView
>
> itemViewContainer -> childViewContainer

The complete look of your code will look like this (run code snippet and see results):

```js
$(function () {

 var app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

  app.addRegions({
  appRegion: '#AppBase'
   });

app.module('App',function(UserModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){

UserModule.UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { fname: '',lname: ''}
});

UserModule.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModule.UserModel,
    comparator: 'lname'
});

UserModule.UserItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: '#user-list',
});

UserModule.TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    id: "mylist",
    className: "table-striped table-bordered",
    template: "#leader-table",
    childView:  UserModule.UserItemView,
    childViewContainer: 'tbody'
});
UserModule.addInitializer(function(){
    var UserList = [];
        UserList.push({fname: 'John',lname: 'Taylor' });
        UserList.push({fname: 'Smith', lname: 'Price'});
    var datalist = new UserModule.UserCollection(UserList);
    var UserCollectionView = new UserModule.TableView({model: new (Backbone.Model.extend({})), collection: datalist});
    app.appRegion.show(UserCollectionView);
});
});

  app.start();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.2.2/backbone.marionette.js"></script>




<div id="AppBase"></div>   
<script type="text/template" id="leader-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class='header'>
      <th>Fistname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="user-list">
  <td><%= fname %></td>
    <td><%= lname %></td>
</script>
```